# Filter with set.has doesn't work as expected

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I'm trying to filter array by `Set.has` like this:

```js
const input = [ 
  { nick: 'Some name', x: 19, y: 24, grp: 4, id: '19340' },
  { nick: 'Some name', x: 20, y: 27, grp: 11, id: '19343' },
  { nick: 'Some name', x: 22, y: 27, grp: 11, id: '19344' },
  { nick: 'Some name', x: 22, y: 30, grp: 11, id: '19350' },
  { nick: 'Some name', x: 22, y: 12, grp: 23, id: '19374' },
  { nick: 'Some name', x: 22, y: 29, grp: 23, id: '19377' } 
];

const grpToOmit = [ 11, 23 ];
const groupToOmitSet = new Set(grpToOmit);

input.filter(it => {
  console.log(groupToOmitSet.has(it.grp))
  return !groupToOmitSet.has(it.grp);
});

console.log(input)
```

So I create collections of unique values from `grpToOmit` array and then I'm checking it within filter function.

This filter doesn't do anything and input array is not changing although `console.log(groupToOmitSet.has(it.grp))` console true few times (I'm using oposit in next line).

Comment: cause `.filter` returns a new array

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.filter` produces a new array, it doesn't mutate the existing one. You need to assign the result to a variable.

```js
const input = [ 
    { nick: 'Some name', x: 19, y: 24, grp: 4, id: '19340' },
    { nick: 'Some name', x: 20, y: 27, grp: 11, id: '19343' },
    { nick: 'Some name', x: 22, y: 27, grp: 11, id: '19344' },
    { nick: 'Some name', x: 22, y: 30, grp: 11, id: '19350' },
    { nick: 'Some name', x: 22, y: 12, grp: 23, id: '19374' },
    { nick: 'Some name', x: 22, y: 29, grp: 23, id: '19377' } 
];

const grpToOmit = [ 11, 23 ];
const groupToOmitSet = new Set(grpToOmit);

const output = input.filter(it => {
  return !groupToOmitSet.has(it.grp);
});

console.log(output)
```